# Delphi: TFileStream & TStringList saving a blank text file

Tags: file, delphi, text, tstringlist, tfilestream

I'm a college student (UK) using delphi for my A2 Computing project. I'm really not very advanced so please bear with me! OK, so I'm using TStringList to save the contents of a TMemoBox to a textfile after encrypting it. However, this wasn't possible due to TStringList showing showing a linebreak after the message which messed up the encryption. I followed [this](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/88917) article, which uses both TStringList and TFIleStream to remove this, but instead of giving me a full textfile, the result is empty. Please could you help save the data rather than not storing it at all? Thanks a lot. Here is a part of my procedure.

```
var
  EmailText : TStringList;
  FileStream : TFileStream;
begin
  FileName := 'email1.txt';
  EmailText := TStringList.Create;
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);          

  EmailText.SaveToStream(FileStream, EmailText.Encoding);
  FileStream.Size := FileStream.Size - Length(System.sLineBreak);           
  EmailText.Add(EmailMessageMemo.Text);                            
  FileStream.Free;
  EmailText.Free;
```

Comment: The `TStringList.Add` method is supposed to add a *line*, meaning that it will append EOL to the argument and add the resulting thing to the string list object. You could try `EmailText.Text := EmailMessageMemo.Text;` instead, which, as far as I know, should copy the contents verbatim.

Comment: @TLama Thanks for the reply, but that still generates a linebreak in my .txt file when it's saved...

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for helping, but that still generates an line break in my document :/

Comment: OK, it's my mistake, I think I'm reading it into the Memo wrong, as the line is generated when the file is read and not when it is saved. I'll have a tinker and let you know

Comment: What you really need to do is get on board with the fact that it is a mistake to encrypt text. Encryption operates on binary. The big thing you are missing is the difference between text and binary. I know that's not what you want to hear, but there it is all the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the advice, but my encryption actually works fine, it was just the fact that displaying the decrypted results messed up because of the line break character!

Comment: Encryption operates on binary. You are probably doing something other than encryption. I'm like a broken record on this topic. You'll never get me to yield.

Comment: I reverted your edit. It was off topic. The question you asked, see above, was why the file you saved was empty.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind - `TStrings` has its own `LineBreak` property, so this code should be using `Length(EmailText.LineBreak)` instead of `Length(System.sLineBreak)`. But that relies on `LineBreak` always encoding to 8bit values without surrogates. A more accurate approach would be to use `EmailText.Encoding.GetByteCount(EmailText.LineBreak)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
EmailText := TStringList.Create; // new string list, empty
FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate); 
EmailText.SaveToStream(FileStream, EmailText.Encoding);
```

So you have saved an empty string list to a file. So your file is consequently empty, because your string list is empty.

I guess you intended to add the content to the string list before you saved it.

```
EmailText := TStringList.Create;
EmailText.AddStrings(EmailMessageMemo.Lines);
FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate); 
EmailText.SaveToStream(FileStream, EmailText.Encoding);
```

The extra string list is needless though. You can do it like this:

```
FileStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate); 
EmailMessageMemo.Lines.SaveToStream(FileStream, TEncoding.Default);
```

I'd also like to point out, as I have done on so many other occasions, that encryption operates on binary rather than text. Of course, if you weren't trying to treat text as binary and vice versa, then you would not suffer from stray line break text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm following your short edit and im getting error: 'TMemo does not contain a member called 'SaveToStream'. Am i just being stupid or is that a genuine problem? Thanks again!

Comment: @TobyFox:  `TMemo` itself does not have a `SaveToStream()` method, but its `Lines` property does, just like David showed you: `EmailMessageMemo.Lines.SaveToStream(...); `